# Type hint for '$this' and other variables in phpFramework::view files?

Tags: php, netbeans

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Variable type hinting in Netbeans (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798477/variable-type-hinting-in-netbeans-php)

**/EDIT**

In php frameworks, in the views, **$this** refers to the controller object. But netbeans doesn't know this (I am guessing neither do other IDEs), so when I hit Ctrl + Space, the code completion doesnt work (says No Sugestions).

Is there some trick, or phpdoc directive that can tell the IDE the types of a variable that isn't declared in the current file (and there is no "include" or require_once either, because the php framework takes care of that by convention, so no explicit include is made).

Also in php frameworks there are other variables besides $this in the view.php files, but putting on the top of the file a php doc for them doesn't seem to do anything either.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has method discovery, you should look into the PHP specialised versions of that - something like Aptana, or Zend Studio.