# phpstorm: autocompletion, __construct and @property declaration

Tags: autocomplete, phpstorm

I got a problem with autocompletion in phpstorm.

The problem is due to __construct() special treatment. how to prevent this special treatment? In my case my variables types are set with @property. In __construct i set the variables but in the way it's impossible for phpstorm to determine it's type.

This __construct special treatment overrides @property statement - how to turn it off?.

Comment: Was my answer the correct answer, or did you resolve the issue you had? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As I found out in a question I asked, `@property` is actually just for magic properties, and the `@var` keyword is supposed to document your class properties.

Source: [ashnazg's Answer to my similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9004669/324527)