# I can't get into the class or function with Crtl key

Tags: php, zend-framework, netbeans, naming

I think my problem lies quite deep and I dont know if somebody can help, but...

This is my Application structure in my Zend project:

```
Application
    Models
        DbTable
    configs
    controllers
    layouts
    views
```

In Models directory i have f.e. Comment.php file which contains "Application_Model_Comment" class.
In DbTable dir i have f.e. Comment.php file which contains "Application_Model_DbTable_Comment" class.

And now, I can create an instance of that classes in controllers but can't get into these files in my IDE clicking ctrl key + mouse button. But I can use these classes in my app so it shouldn't be the classes autoloading problem.

As you can see, the example class contains a word "Model" when folder name is "Models", what personally suprises me. But classes are working fine.

So... do you have any idea why I can't use very good method to stepping into the classes and write phpDocumentation well? Other "classes links" like Zend_Something works fine.

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

I closed the project in Projects tab and opened it once again :)

Comment: It's help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798477/variable-type-hinting-in-netbeans-php

Comment: It itsn't answer to my question. Read my topic again and come back after that.